# Unable to check is schema is present first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schema

I've created a SQL  script that will release a process to numerous SQL  Server instances so I want to check if a paticular schema is present before creating the schema.

I'm using the below and it creates an error but I don't understand why?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas s WHERE s.name = 'SQLInstance_Baseline')
    CREATE SCHEMA [SQLInstance_Baseline];
```

If I wrap the `CREATE SCHEMA [SQLInstance_Baseline]` in an `EXEC` i.e. `EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [SQLInstance_Baseline]')` it works fine, but I don't really like doing this for best practice reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The schema creation has to be the only statement within it's own batch, with no statements preceeding or following it.

As the `IF` statement is considered to be in the same batch, the statement is syntactically incorrect.

You have to wrap the schema creation within an `EXEC`, so it is considered to be in a separate batch.

Therefore the correct syntax for what you are doing is:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'SQLInstance_Baseline')) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE SCHEMA [SQLInstance_Baseline] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]')
END
```

Comment: The version you've used above already worked using the syntax I provided lwer down in the comment, I understand it needs to be the only statement withing its own batch but regardless of me putting the syntax (minus the exec wrapping) into a begin end statement it still doesn't work.

Comment: Because the IF statement counts as the same batch...

Comment: Therefore 'IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'SQLInstance_Baseline'))
BEGIN
    CREATE SCHEMA [SQLInstance_Baseline] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
END' should work?

Comment: You HAVE to use EXEC. That is the only way...

Comment: Thanks, I got the impression there wasn't a way around it.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, actually it's not. In the `IF EXISTS` you can use `SET NOEXEC ON` -> `GO` -> `CREATE SCHEMA ...` -> `GO` -> `SET NOEXEC OFF`